# * foreach inside foreach codeigniter 2?

Tags: codeigniter, foreach, nested

In codeigniter 2.1 I'm trying to display channels by category. So if i have a category called Film, i should see a list of Channels within Film. I tried a nested foreach loop to accomplish this but can't seem to get it to work.

My tables structure is something like this but more complicated:

[image: Database structure]

- My model:

  ```
  <?php

  class Pages_model extends CI_Model {


  function get_channels_by_categ_tv()
  {

    $this->db->select('categories.category_name, channels.channel_name');
    $this->db->from('type_categ');
    $this->db->join('categories', 'categories.category_id = type_categ.category_id');
    $this->db->join('channels', 'channels.channel_id = type_categ.channel_id');
    $this->db->order_by('categories.category_id');
  //$this->db->group_by(array('categories.category_id')); 
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() == 0)
    {
      #no channels
      return false;
    }

    return $query->result_array();
  }

  }
  ```
- in the view:

  ```
            <ul class="slides">
              <li>
                  <?php foreach ($category_chaneels as $category): ?>
                  <div class="programe-tv_link">
                      <p><?=$category['category_name'];?></p>
                         <dd> <a href=""> >> <?=$category['channel_name'];?></a></dd>
                  </div>
                  <?php endforeach; ?>                  
              </li>
            </ul>
  ```
- controller (Pages):

  ```
  public function index()
  {

  $data['category_chaneels'] = $this->pages_model->get_channels_by_categ_tv();

  $this->template->page_view($data);
  }
  ```

I atached image 1 and image 2, i need result like image 2 not 1.

PS. One channel can have many categories.

[image]
Can you help me ? THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My final code is this. Maby sombody need this.

```
    <div id="programe-tv-slide" class="flexslider">
        <strong>Programe TV</strong>
        <div class="redLine"></div>

        <?php $cat_cnl = array(); 
              $list = array(); 
              $i=1;
                 foreach ($category_chaneels as $option) { 
                    $catname = $option['category_name'];
                    $chlname = $option['channel_name'];

                    $cat_cnl[$catname][$i] = $chlname;
                    $list[$i] = $catname;
              $i++;
                 }; 
        ?>
        <?php 
            $rows = array_chunk($cat_cnl, 4, TRUE);
            foreach ($rows as $row) {  //var_dump($rows);
        ?>

          <ul class="slides">    
            <?php
                echo ('<li>');
                foreach ($row as $category => $channels) {
                    echo '<div class="programe-tv_link">'; 
                    echo '<p>' . $category . '</p>'; 
                        foreach ($channels as $channel) {
                                echo '<dd><a href="">' . $channel . '</a></dd> '; 
                        };
                    echo '</div>'; 
                    };      
                echo ('</li>'); 
            ?>
          </ul>
          <?php }; ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your view, try

```
<?php $cat_shown = ''; ?>
<div class="programe-tv_link">
    <?php foreach ($category_chaneels as $category): ?>    
        <?php
        if ($cat_shown != $category['category_name']) {
            echo '<p>' . $category['category_name'] . '</p>';
            $cat_shown = $category['category_name'];
        }
        ?>
        <dd><a href=""> >> <?=$category['channel_name'];?></a></dd>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi stealthyninja, how can i view this in diferents DIV and limit 1 div -> 3 li,